# speaker-test works only once

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, alsa

I'm learning Linux and I've installed Arch 4.7.5 on Virtual Box 5.1.6.

I've installed `alsamixer` and tried running `speaker-test` but it didn't work. I've found [this](https://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/fixing-audio-in-linux-guests-virtualbox/) guide which partially fixed my problem. Now when I run this test I hear static in both speakers, but only the first time I run it. If I try running it again, it forever shows me `0 - Front Left` and doesn't do anything.

Maybe this is a bug and I should report it?